# get items greater than given datetime and less than given datetime in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, datetime, date-comparison

I have an array that has a startTime. I want to get items where startTime in between 2020-12-10 09:30:00 and 2020-12-10 13:20:00. I am using the filter method to get the items from the array.

startTime>'2020-12-10 09:30:00' // is working, returns array with 6 items

but when i add startTime>'2020-12-10 09:30:00' &&  startTime<'2020-12-10 13:20:00' // returns null

not able to understand why it not filtering the result when I use less than

here is my code

```
var empStart = empShift.filter(item => {
    return item.startTime>'2020-12-10 09:30:00' && item.startTime<'2020-12-10 
    13:20:00'
    })
```

Comment: What you're showing here are strings, not `Date` objects. If the value of `startTime` is a `Date` object, this will be problematic.

Comment: just past the dummy data which you are using ```empShift```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response guys I came to know whats my mistake

var empStart = empShift.filter(item => {

```
return new date(item.startTime).getTime() >'2020-12-10 09:30:00' && new 
date(item.startTime).getTime() <'2020-12-10 13:20:00'

})
```

new date(//variable).getTime() // solved my issue

Comment: That's not going to fix the problem. `getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch, and they are being compared with strings.

Comment: I stored date in a variable like new date(item.startTime).getTime() >new date(neededDate).getTime()

Comment: I read your answer; repeating it doesn't change the problem.So if you run `new Date().getTime()`, it should return a value like `1610570971995`. Do you see how comparing that to the string `'2020-12-10 09:30:00'` doesn't make much sense? Another example: try running `new Date().getTime() < '2321-02-01 13:20:00'` Certainly that should be true? Today is obviously less than February 1st 2321! But it returns false. If, however, you run `new Date().getTime() < new Date('2321-02-01T13:20:00').getTime()`, it does return true, because you're comparing two of the same type of value.

Comment: `new Date('2020-12-10 09:30:00')` creates an invalid date in at least one current browser, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)